# Auto click button on page load (window.onload)

Tags: javascript, triggers, webflow

I’m building a site on Webflow using Finsweet’s CMS Combine and CMS Sort on my homepage. I’m trying to set up a hidden button to be triggered automatically when the page loads so the button automatically sort the items on the home page by name.

The script I have on the page works, however, when browsing the site, for example, on 3-4 navigations back to the home page, it stops working and the items are no longer sorted by name.

[Site Preview](https://jans-cool-site-758125.webflow.io/)

The script I’m using:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
document.querySelector(".fs_cmssort_button").click();
};
</script>
```

Can someone please take a look at it? Thanks!

I've tried different codes that I found but still nothing works as It should.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on the subject, but I think what's going on is that you are setting the onload attribute in a seperate place that you set the button. Therefore, if the button loaded in before the script section was able to run, it wouldn't be able to play the onLoad function (since the onLoad event was already called and nothing was there).

To fix this, I think you could set a defer attribute to your script, which would only make it run after everything as loaded in. Since we know that everything has loaded in, we can just immediatly press the sort button without worrying if it has loaded or not.

I apologize if this isn't correct at all, I do believe it's worth a try though.

Comment: Can you please give more details on the solution?

Comment: Basically just replace your script with <script defer> document.querySelector(".fs_cmssort_button").click(); </script>